# Using Variable To Access WPF Element

Tags: c#, wpf, variables

I have a number of Grid elements in a WPF Grid. Each Grid is named as 'DocumentPage1', 'DocumentPage2','DocumentPage3', etc.

If I wish to edit 'DocumentPage' + An'int'Variable, what am I to do?

This does not work:

```
...
int PageToAccess = 2;
"DocumentPage" + PageToAccess.Height = 200; //This does not work
...
```

Comment: Put them in an array.

Comment: Just asking, put what in an array? Any hint would be useful. Thank you!

Comment: Put the controls in an array (in your constructor).  You can them access them by index from the array.

Comment: Use VisualTreeHelper.. like the answer from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/how-can-i-find-wpf-controls-by-name-or-type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [FindName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get a object by its name.

```
...
int PageToAccess = 2;
((Control)FindName("DocumentPage" + PageToAccess)).Height = 200;
...
```